# Setting transparent colour on an image

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to import a set of graphs (as jpeg images) slightly offset from each other to build a surface plot. As each image is overlayed on the previous I need to set its transparent colour so they all show through. I cannot get the transparency set.

```
n = 1
Do While MyFile <> ""   ' Start the loop.
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture _
        FileName:=MyPath & "\" & MyFile, _
        LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=PosLeft, Top:=PosTop, Width:=SpecWidth, Height:=SpecHeight

    With myDocument.Shapes(n)
        With .PictureFormat
            .TransparentBackground = msoTrue
            .TransparencyColor = vbBlack
        End With
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    PosLeft = PosLeft + IncLeft
    PosTop = PosTop + IncTop
    MyFile = Dir()   ' Get next entry.
    n = n + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Transparency is not yet in the VBA object model. The commands you're trying to use are for the older method of setting a single transparent color for an image.

It's possible to make shapes transparent. If you give the transparent shape a picture fill, the picture will then be transparent. Here's a page with that workaround: [Use VBA to Make a Picture Transparent in Microsoft Office](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1052086/Use-VBA-to-Make-a-Picture-Transparent-in-Microsoft)

Comment: Thanks but I have found the problem. The software I was using to generate the graphs did not give the exact black colour that my vba code expected. Once I changed that my code worked as expected.